Fernco sewage connection under tension
The main sewage pipe under a rental property of mine has a long span with a 3 wye right in the middle of it. The geniuses that built the place didn't add any strap support and also decided to lay out all the heavy main electric cables on top of the pipe.
To no surprise, 20 years later when I came to own the place I discovered this and found that the wye was cracked and leaking. I had a plumber come out and he put in a new wye with fernco metal shielded couplers ( I'm in CA and idk if this is code but whatever if it works for 10+yrs).
Of course the biggest thing I asked him to do was to make sure he fixed the angle, removed the sag, and supported it with straps. Well, I finally had a chance to inspect his work (the property is hours away and the access to the pipe requires 20min of truly horrible crawling), to my dismay the plumber used plastic straps which had clearly broke resulting in the pipe sagging yet again.
While I was down there, rigged up some pieces of wood on some rocks to hold it up. I plan to add metal strap supports but that probably won't be till next year.
What concerns me is if my temp fix will last for a year (or just end up sinking back into the dirt by then )? more importantly though, can the ferncos handle significant force? The pipe naturally wants to sag like a V shape (the right hand side of the pipe is too high compared to the left) - so I'm putting a good amount of force on the whole setup to try to straighten it out. How bad is this?

Higher res pic https://ibb.co/x7k5M9F
(Note it looks like from the pic that the cables are still weighing down the pipes but they're not really, I added a hangar out of picture so theres no more significant weight on the PVC from them)

This sounds like it would be worth your while to run to the local hardware store and buy some strapping and get the issue fixed once and for all.

This sounds like it would be worth your while to run to the local hardware store and buy some strapping and get the issue fixed once and for all.
There is no way we can calculate the amount of force on the ferncos, so any advice here would be only a guess.

Fair enough, I will add strapping to be safe. However my second question still stands because even with strapping the ferncos are going to have a good amount of force on them .are they liable to crack from that?

The ferncos will bend rather than crack. The ABS will crack first.

2 hours of crawling around but got some strap up https://ibb.co/Qj4stGF
https://ibb.co/b7hrMCm did what I could to fix the angle but the far right hand side of the pipe is sitting on a foundation wall that is too high. The whole wye is roughly level now, which isn't ideal but is certainly not as bad as having a 2 inch dip in the middle. Im hopeful this will help reduce the clogs at least a bit
